# How do I port newlib?

Tags: c, newlib

I want to write my own kernel but I'm stuck on porting newlib for my cross-compiler.

1. Which version of [newlib](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/newlib/index.html) do I download?
2. Where do I put the system call [stubs](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib)? Is the minimal implementation enough? Do I have to rebuild newlib if I decide to edit the system calls at a later date?
3. My kernel exposes all the system calls on interrupt 0x80 (128d) so I just had to put a bit of inline assembly into each stub to do what I needed it to do. It's up to you how to implement them in relation to your kernel.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Is there any reason not to download the latest version?
2. Look at `newlib/libc/sys/*/syscall.c` and generally at `libgloss` (it's included with the newlib sources). In fact you can put them wherever you like, as long as the linker can find them, but those places are where other ports are kept. Newlib expects to find functions with particular names, and all you have to do is implement them (I vaguely remember there being 13 essential ones, plus others like `fork` that you can have just return an error code).
3. Yes, you just insert whatever code you like into the syscall stubs.

You'll also need to provide `crt0.o`; this provides the real entry point to the program, initializes memory (particularly the `bss`), grabs `argv` from wherever your OS keeps it, and calls `main`. There's usually a bit in there to call `atexit` handlers after `main` returns, and passes the exit code back to the OS.